# facebook integration iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

i try to integrate facebook api in my app for publish post to wall.
Now i integrate code in my appdelegate but i don't know receive this errore at this line:
"initWithAppId: not found"

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"
#import "Facebook.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
   UIWindow *window;
   UITabBarController *tabBarController;
   Facebook *facebook;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) Facebook *facebook;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"168377643283604"];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
  }
```

Comment: Have you just copied and pasted this code from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_APP_ID" andDelegate:self];
```

Instead of

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_APP_ID" ];
```

and Don't forget to add `YOUR APP ID` in `.plist` file too.

Add this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate,FBSessionDelegate>
```

Comment: I have insert APP ID in .plist. If i add "andDelegate:self" obtain this error: <(id<FBSessionDelegate>)>